# Why dnsmasq failed to create listening socket for 172.17.0.1?Cannot assign request

Tags: linux, dns

I installed dnsmasq and resolveconf. I add my docker0 ip

```
/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d$ cat tail
nameserver 172.17.0.1
```

I got this error

```
systemctl status dnsmasq.service
× dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-11-18 12:52:00 WET; 10min ago
    Process: 1934 ExecStartPre=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq checkconfig (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2023 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-exec (code=exited, status=2)
        CPU: 46ms

нов 18 12:52:00 miki-IdeaPad systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...
нов 18 12:52:00 miki-IdeaPad dnsmasq[2023]: dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 172.17.0.1: Cannot ass>
нов 18 12:52:00 miki-IdeaPad dnsmasq[2023]: failed to create listening socket for 172.17.0.1: Cannot assign reque>
нов 18 12:52:00 miki-IdeaPad dnsmasq[2023]: FAILED to start up
нов 18 12:52:00 miki-IdeaPad systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDAR>
нов 18 12:52:00 miki-IdeaPad systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
нов 18 12:52:00 miki-IdeaPad systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq
```

my resolve.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search netcabo.pt
nameserver 172.17.0.1
```

It seems that I do not understand how systemd resolves name servers.
What is wrong here?